# Oracle lib for node.js / Oracle connection: which one is better?

Tags: oracle, node.js

I need to be able to call Oracle stored procedure from a node.js client.
Among node-oracle and node-db-oracle, which lib is the best one to perform this ?

Also, is there any use of one of those libs in production ?

Answer (score 2):

I am using node-oracle regularly to import spatial data from GBKN/NEN1878 files into Oracle 11. Works like a charm.

For the GBKN data I use a self-written parser (https://github.com/StevenLooman/nen1878reader) (shameless self-promotion :)), the importer script itself is not freely available at the moment.

When I looked at node-db-oracle, it used a mix of JavaScript and SQL constructs to build the SQL sent to the databse. From the node-db-oracle README, https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle :

```
this.query().select('*').from('users').execute(function(error, rows) { ... }
```

I prefer to simply feed the library a SQL-string, instead of some combination of both.

Both libraries probably work as advertised. It's a matter of your own preference to how the libraries are used.

Comment: To come back to this answer, I've moved to using the SQL*Loader instead of doing INSERT INTO-SQL-statements. The SQL*Loader is several orders faster. I went from ~3 hours per file (at least, probably more), to 2 + 5 minutes per file. (Converting, loading.)

Also, I had some memory-issues. For every record, an INSERT INTO was performed. The input files contain several million records. As a result, the used memory kept growing until the process ran out of memory. Probably due to the database server not keeping up, or flooding it with too many statements at the same time.

Comment: I agree. this is the ugly way to use db. But, this.query().execute('select * from users') also works. You are free to choose either one.

Comment: I'm not surprised - SQL*Loader will always win out on bulk data loading.